# Create a facebook login button with javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to add a facebook login button using the dom (createElement, appendChild...)
Following the facebook developper website, i wrote :

```
var loginFB = document.createElement('div');
    loginFB.id = "loginFacebook";
    loginFB.class="fb-login-button";
    loginFB.innerHTML = "Login with Facebook";
```

I also add in my javascript script the facebook function required.

And a div in my web page :

But this doesn't seem to work. I have a "Login with facebook" that appears but totally black.

Do you have an idea of how to achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I also add in my javascript script the facebook function required.

What exactly does that mean?

If you are adding XFBML tags after the SDK has finished loading, you have to call [FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/) to explicitly have the document (or parts thereof) re-parsed for these tags.

Comment: Thank you, it is now working.Another problem was the loginFB.class that didn't worked. I used loginFB.setAttribute("class","fb-login-button") and it worked with the parse. Thanks again.

Comment: Of course, `class` is a reserved word in JavaScript (although not really “in use” as of now). Therefor, to read/write the class of a DOM element, you have to use `element.className`. (Although in most cases, setAttribute will work as well.)